# PhpStorm: what to do with unhandled exceptions when preconditions are met

Tags: php, phpstorm

I really like the PhpStorm inspection tools. They help me a lot to write better code. Now I have the following situation and I am asking myself what's the best way to deal with such situations.

I have a function f with some precondition, for example like in the following code:

```
/**
 * @param int $x
 * @throws PreconditionException x is negative
 */
 public function f(int $x): int
 {
   if ($x < 0) {
     throw new PreconditionException("the input x is negative");
   }
 }
```

Then I use this function somewhere lets say the following:

```
f(5);
```

Now PhpStorm warns me with "Unhandled exception". But in this case I know that the exception will not be thrown, so adding a try block makes not really sense. Should I simply ignore this warning or what's the best way to deal with that?

Comment: Just for the sample code provided: just suppress inspection for that line (`f(5);`). In general it all depends on real code and how and where it's used. For example: you may make 2 functions: one for internal that assumes that data is absolutely fine and one for public usage where such checks are made (and it calls internal one to do the actual job). You may also write such function with no checks at all and ensure that data passes integrity checks before calling the actual function (in this case function must be rather for internal usage only). etc

Comment: I did it now with suppress, but now if at some point this function throws another exception I won't get any unhandled exception warnings for the new exception, so this is in my opinion also not perfect. Furthermore if f(5); occurrs in another function then I also get the warning "PHPDoc comment doesn't contain all necessary @throw tag(s)", which I need again to suppress. But again I may want warnings for other statements of the function, so the suppression in this case is also not perfect.

Comment: Well .. there is nothing in PHPDoc or PhpStorm to identify that here this exception can be thrown and here it will definitely not. You either: handle possible exception, allow to pass it further to calling method (by annotating `@throws` in this method) or suppress it (whole inspection, so it will work on any exception that such method can throw).

Comment: How do you suppress an exception?

Comment: /** @noinspection PhpUnhandledExceptionInspection */

this tells phpstorm to ignore the unhandled exception inspection for the next line

Comment: @blacktemplar Please submit this as an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately you need two `@noinspection` tags: One for the missing throws statement in the doc comment, and one for the unhandled exception in the code itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From phpStorm version 2018.1 you can exclude any exceptions from analysis. Go to `preferences->Languages & Frameworks->PHP` and open `Analysis` tab.

[image]

Here you can add exceptions to `Unchecked Exceptions` list

Comment: That would blanket ignore exceptions of a certain type, not specific instances as the question asks. Useful to know, though.

Comment: In this example you can make `PreconditionException` extend `LogicException` or `RuntimeException` (depending on whether the value depends on your logic or external input).

Comment: Exceptions like for example LogicExceptions are ment to literally tell you "you have bug in code", and if they trigger it means something is heavly impaired. OP probably want to use it this way. Imagine it's like constantly validating itself code, and its perfectly valid approach if you test code extensively. Whenever your code is getting to point of unknown behaviour, its better to crash than cause damage.

Answer (score 9):

`@noinspection` tag can be used to instruct PhpStorm to suppress an inspection.
The tag can be used above the line, above the method or on top of the file after `<?php` word:

```
/** @noinspection PhpDocMissingThrowsInspection */
/**
 *
 * Cancels order.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public static function cancel()
{
    if (!self::inProgress()) return false;
    /** @noinspection PhpUnhandledExceptionInspection*/
    static::current()->delete();
    return true;
}
```

List of inspections can be found in this gist: https://gist.github.com/discordier/ed4b9cba14652e7212f5

---

You can also disable it via interface. <kbd>ALT+ENTER</kbd> then right arrow and `Suppress ...`
[image]

Comment: This works, but: You need two `@noinspection` tags, and these are specific to PhpStorm. It would be nicer to have a phpdoc tag for this.

Comment: @donquixote, I agree that needing two `@noinspections` is not ideal (the one at the call site should prevent the warning about the doc block). But, your second sentence doesn't make sense. Why would you need a PHPDoc tag for NOT throwing an exception??

Comment: @R.Agnese When you write code in a team, or you intend to publish the code, you typically want it to be agnostic to the IDE, or agnostic to your specific configuration of the IDE. Even though PhpStorm is the only serious php IDE that I know of that people use these days :) So if you litter the code with IDE-specific inspection suppression comments, your team might reject it, or it might just feel wrong when publishing it.

Comment: @donquixote I agree: I hate tool-specific magic comments. But, in this case, it's not PHP that is issuing these warnings about unhandled exceptions--it's PHPStorm. So, if we want to write IDE-agnostic PHP code, then we can just ignore the light-warning-squiggles that PHPStorm is showing us. You don't need a PHPDoc tag for ignored exception types because the tool should respect the PHPDoc tag: if there's no `@throws FooException` tag, then it should assume that the function doesn't throw a `FooException` (I know PHPStorm will still sometimes "know", but it probably shouldn't do that, IMO).

Answer (score 8):

The correct way is add `@throws` tag into documentation ([PhpStorm manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php-unhandled-exception.html)).
For example:

```
    /**
     * @param $userId
     * @return array|null
     * @throws \Exception   <---------------------------
     */
    public static function send($userId)
    {
        if (empty($userId)) {
            throw new \Exception("User ID is missing", 1);
        }
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: This is the best way I think. First you add PHPDocument, second, the PHPStorm inspection dissapear !!

Comment: This actually is the worst way to deal with assert-like exceptions that detect real bugs instead of recoverable failures. If you do this, every callsite will have to handle that exception or get called out for not doing so by PHPStorm. Better throw a special exception reserved for detected Bugs and mark that to be ignored by the inspector.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question at all. The question is already assuming a function with a documented @throws tag. They're asking what to do at the *call site* when we're sure that the call will *not* throw because we've already done all necessary validation.

Comment: The problem with putting a throws docblock tag when the method doesn't throw is when you change any child methods which do the throwing you have to remember to come to yours that doesn't throw and remove or edit the throw. Urgh no

Answer (score 6):

What helps for me is to set `@throws` to `Null`

Example:

```
    /**
     * @return SomeObject
     * @throws Null
     *
     */
```

Comment: It shouldn't be an answer, adding useless code (even in phpdoc) is a bad habit. You add code, but without utility or visibility. Better to disable inspection.