# PhpStorm Unhandled FacebookSDKException

Tags: php, facebook, phpstorm

For some reason Facebook SDK is throwing a whole bunch of "Unhandled Exception" warnings and I wonder if I did something wrong or its just something ill have to disable like suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618511/phpstorm-what-to-do-with-unhandled-exceptions-when-preconditions-are-met) question?

```
//Unhandled \Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '10000000000000',
    'app_secret' => '10000000000000000000000',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v3.0',
]);


//Unhandled \Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId('10000000000000');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();
$response->getGraphUser()


//Exception 'FacebookResponseException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block
try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e)
```

Comment: Methods like `validateAppId` could throw an exception, https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/2f9639c15ae043911f40ffe44080b32bac2c5280/src/Facebook/Authentication/AccessTokenMetadata.php#L326 PHPStorm has analyzed the code of that method, seen that it could throw an exception - and therefor warns you that you are not catching it. So, either catch it, ignore the warnings, or configure PHPStorm to shut up about this :-)

Comment: You could of course also group several steps together in one try/catch block, that catches all exceptions - like the initialization and validation of the app id. If _either_ of those two goes wrong, there is no much point in proceeding anyway.